# Applying Shannon's Noiseless Coding Theorem

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

I'm working through some exam questions in preparation for exam season. We are given:

"A discrete memoryless source W outputs the symbol a with probability 1/2, the
symbol b with probability 1/4, the symbol c with probability 1/8 and the symbol d with probability 1/8...
a->111, b->011, c->01, d->0"

Following Huffman encoding I have that a->0, b->10, c->110, d->111.

The Question is:
"Show that the average word length of this Huffman encoding satisfies the
lower bound given by Shannon’s Noiseless Coding Theorem."

So easy to compute that H(w) = 1/2(1) + 1/4(2) + 1/8(3) + 1/8(3) = 7/4

But I don't understand how to compute ¯n so I can't attain ¯n = 7/4 to conclude!

Comment: Compute the average number of bits needed to encode $N$ symbols, and compare with $N H(W) = N\frac{7}{4}$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%27s_source_coding_theorem